# Order by number of matches in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to get a list of best matching items giving a list of tags with the data below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testing_items;
CREATE TEMP TABLE testing_items(
    id bigserial primary key,
    tags text[]
);
CREATE INDEX ON testing_items using gin (tags);

INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) VALUES ('{123,456, abc}');
INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) VALUES ('{222,333}');
INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) VALUES ('{222,555}');
INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) VALUES ('{222,123}');
INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) VALUES ('{222,123,555,666}');
```

I have the tags `222`,`555` and `666`. How can I get a list like this?

`gin` index must be used because there will be tons of records.

| id | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

`id` 1 should not be in the list because it doesn't match any tag:

| id | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnest tags, filter unnested elements and aggregate remaining ones:

```
select id, count(distinct u) as matches
from (
    select id, u
    from testing_items,
    lateral unnest(tags) u
    where u in ('222', '555', '666')
    ) s
group by 1
order by 2 desc

 id | matches 
----+---------
  5 |       3
  3 |       2
  2 |       1
  4 |       1
(4 rows)
```

---

Considering all the answers, it seems that this query combines good sides of each of them:

```
select id, count(*) 
from testing_items,
unnest(array['11','5','8']) u
where tags @> array[u] 
group by id 
order by 2 desc, 1;
```

It has the best performance in Eduardo's test.

Comment: I believe the IN clause will not use the GIN index because the lack of @> operator

Comment: Right, to use the index you have to reverse comparison like in paqash's version (nice try).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents using unnest and array contains:

```
select id, count(*) 
from (
  select unnest(array['222','555','666']) as tag, * 
  from testing_items
) as w 
where tags @> array[tag] 
group by id 
order by 2 desc
```

Results:

`+------+---------+
|   id |   count |
|------+---------|
|    5 |       3 |
|    3 |       2 |
|    2 |       1 |
|    4 |       1 |
+------+---------+`

Comment: this seems to be how you check an array against another array. is there something similar i can do to check a string of multiple tags against an array of tags?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tested with 10 million records with 3 tags each with random numbers between 0 and 100:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE testing_items IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO testing_items (tags) SELECT (ARRAY[trunc(random() * 99 + 1), trunc(random() * 99 + 1), trunc(random() * 99 + 1)]) FROM generate_series(1, 10000000) s;
COMMIT;
```

I've put an `ORDER BY c DESC, id LIMIT 5` for not waiting for big responses.

@paqash and @klin solutions have similar performance. My laptop runs them in 12 seconds with the tags 11, 8 and 5.

But this runs in 4.6 seconds:

```
SELECT id, count(*) as c
FROM (
SELECT id FROM   testing_items WHERE  tags @> '{11}'
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM   testing_items WHERE  tags @> '{8}'
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM   testing_items WHERE  tags @> '{5}'
) as items
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY c DESC, id
LIMIT 5
```

But I still think there is a faster way.

Comment: I think you've found the proper way. Unnest is costly while the simple queries with a constant on right hand side take full advantage of GIN index.

Comment: @> do not use GIN index

Answer (score 0):

Check it here: http://rextester.com/UTGO74511

If you are using a GIN index, use &&:

```
select *
from testing_items
where not (ARRAY['333','555','666'] && tags);


id | tags
--- -------------
 1  123456abc
 4  222123
```

Comment: This returns only the item that matches all tags